# Cloud Composer, Airflow - web_server_worker_timeout environmental variable

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need to get accounts from a web service that might take over the current default of 60 seconds.

It seems that my workers are constantly going into timeout, which can be modified under the `web_server_worker_timeout` environmental variable in `webserver` group. However, this variable cannot be modified under cloud composer.

Any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you enable the asynchronous DAG loading (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface#asynchronous-load) and see if you notice any improvements? This will speed up the webserver by not requiring all dags to load on each request.

Comment: this option is no more available on composer2

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to custom this, but in composer2 you can select the kubernetes limit cpu for the webserver.

with 0.5cpu on a ENVIRONMENT_SIZE_SMALL my webserver usually fail during 5 minutes ( the 2 workers timeout ) before reaching a stable state.

Try setting more than 0.5cpu to your webserver